# My taskbar doesn't slide down and up

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, graphics

I have been using windows 7 for some time, and I noticed that my toolbar (which I have hidden) have been acting a little bit weird. Normally, when I hover my cursor over it, it gently and smoothly slides up into view. Now it just instantly appears.

Is there a setting to this? I am afraid I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the same visual effects setting that determines whether or not menus slide or just pop in/out.

1. Go to System Properties (right-click on Computer and select Properties, or hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>)
2. In the left-hand pane, click on "Advanced system settings"
3. Under "Performance", click on "Settings..."
4. Check the "Fade or slide menus into view" option
5. Click "OK" twice